# Search for specific folder name in filtered path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to search for a specific folder name from filtered path.

For example:

I have some folders like on disk m:

```
M:\
├───2.46.567
│   └───A
├───3.09.356
│   └───A
├───4.05.123
│   └───A
└───4.05.124
    └───B
```

I want to search folder A only from 4.05.xxx dir. And also i want to check is this folder is last one contains folder A.

I try something like the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path m:\* -recurse -filter '*4.05*' | sort -descending LastWriteTime
```

Can I do this in PowerShell?

Comment: You doubled `M:\4.05.124\B` In general Get-ChildItem allows wildcards on several levels in a path not just the last - no recurse needed. `gci M:\4.05.*\A -Directory`

Comment: I think -Directory command is not available in powershell 2.0

Comment: Well in powershell `dir` is an *alias* for gci=Get-ChildItem. Here `-Directory` is a parameter/argument for gci to select only directories no files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) allows wildcards on several levels in a path not just the last - no recurse needed.

```
Get-ChildItem 'M:\4.05.*\A' -Directory | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime
```

In the above tree this returns just one entry:

```
    Directory: M:\4.05.123


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019-08-30     12:10                A
```

An alternative with the same result based on above tree:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'M:\4.05.*' -Filter A -Recurse -Directory | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime
```

## PowerShell Version 2 variant

```
Get-ChildItem 'M:\4.05.*\A' | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
    Sort-Object -Desc LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1 | Set-Location
```

Comment: This is ok, but Can i select this path? When I add  'code'select -f 1 name'code', powershell return name of my folder. I need to get path like M:\4.05.123. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course, presuming you want only one `$MyPath = gci 'M:\4.05.*\A  -Dir | Sort -Desc LastWriteTime|Select -First 1` otherwise `Select -Last 1`

Comment: If you want to Select that folder as current you can directly pipe to Set-Location. `gci 'M:\4.05.*\A'  -Dir | Sort -Desc LastWriteTime|Select -First 1|Set-Location`

Comment: When I add -Dir i get error, that Get-ChildItem: a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'dir'

Comment: There was a missing single quote, what powershell version do you use? `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: 'Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8784
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1'

Comment: See changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
param(
$SourceDir = "M:\"
)
$a = gci $SourceDir | foreach { $i = gci $sourcedir\$_ -Name ; if($i.equals("A")) {"$_"} }

for($h=0;$h -le $a.Length-1; $h++ ) {
if($a[$h] -like "4.05.*") {
$a[$h]
if( $a[$h].equals($a[$a.length-1])) {
"It is the last one."
}}}
```

This will return all folders that contain a folder "A" and have "4.05." as part of its name. It will also return whether or not it is the last folder in the array, therefore also the last folder that contains "A".

Comment: But can I filter folders A from all folders contains '4.05' in name?

Comment: @terrorDoPappao I'm afraid that I dont quite understand the question. If you want the subfoler "A" of the returned folder, you may just be best off if you added a "\A" to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Resolve-Path`.

```
(Resolve-Path "M:\4.05.*\A").ProviderPath
```

This returns the string (not the folder object!) of the paths you're after.

Comment: But it may also return a string array without a way to sort by LastWriteTime as the properties are gone.

Comment: That's true.  I didn't realise it was a requirement (it said "last folder with A", but I didn't see that it was related to last modified).  `Resolve-Path` cannot be used in that case.